# Joining with NULLs

Tags: mysql

There are a lot of questions about joins and null, but i couldn't find one that matched this particular schema. I have 3 pretty simple tables.

```
+---------+
| service |
+---------+
| id      |
| name    |
+---------+

+-----------+
| propnames |
+-----------+
| id        |
| name      |
| sort      |
+-----------+

+----------+
| props    |
+----------+
| sid      |
| pid      |
| value    |
+----------+
```

I would like to be able to add a property (to propnames) and query my services, joining my properties (props) and know which properties haven't been set yet.

If this is services

```
(id), (name)
1, "AAA"
2, "BBB"
```

This is propnames

```
(id), (name), (sort)
1, "property_a", 1
2, "property_b", 2
3, "property_c", 3
```

This is props

```
(service.id), (propname.id), (value)
1, 1, "Service AAA has property_a value"
1, 2, "Service AAA has property_b value"
2, 1, "Service BBB has property_a value"
```

Then ultimately my query will produce this:

```
(service.id), (service.name), (property.id), (property.name), (props.value)
1, "AAA", 1, "property_a", "Service AAA has property_a value"
1, "AAA", 2, "property_b", "Service AAA has property_b value"
1, "AAA", 3, "property_c", NULL
2, "BBB", 1, "property_a", "Service BBB has property_a value"
2, "BBB", 2, "property_b", NULL
2, "BBB", 3, "property_c", NULL
```

IDEALLY, it would be sorted by service.name ASC -then- property.sort

Currently the incomplete query is:

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, p.id, p.name, props.value 
FROM service.s 
LEFT JOIN propnames p ON s.id = p.sid 
LEFT JOIN props ON props.pid = p.id 
ORDER BY s.name ASC, p.sort ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows.  Then use `left join` to find the matches:

```
select s.id, s.name, p.id, p.name, props.value 
from services s cross join
     propnames p left join
     props
     on props.sid = s.id and props.pid = p.id;
```